# wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'NET_SALARY'

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have created procedure called NET_SALARY. I'm entering proper arguments Number then also it is gives me error.

Code used to run procedure by me

**EXECUTE NET_SALARY(10000,0.15);**

I'm getting error as

Error starting at line : 1 in command -
BEGIN NET_SALARY(10000,0.5); END;
Error report -
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'NET_SALARY'
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:

```
create or replace NONEDITIONABLE PROCEDURE NET_SALARY 
(
  SALARY IN NUMBER ,
  C_PCT IN NUMBER , 
  TOT_SAL OUT NUMBER 
) AS 
    COMM NUMBER;
    GROSS NUMBER;
    IT NUMBER;
BEGIN
  IF C_PCT IS NULL THEN
    GROSS := SALARY;
    IT := SALARY*0.1;
  ELSE
    COMM := SALARY*C_PCT;
    GROSS := SALARY+COMM;
    IF COMM<500 THEN
        IT := GROSS*0.15;
    ELSE
        IT := GROSS*0.2;
    END IF;
    TOT_SAL := GROSS - IT;
  END IF;
END NET_SALARY;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing the OUT parameter while calling the procedure. Should be e.g.

```
declare
  l_tot_sal number;
begin
  net_salary(10000, 0.15, l_tot_sal);
  dbms_output.put_line('Total salary is ' || l_tot_sal);
end;
/
```

---

From my point of view, as you're calculating *something* and returning the result, consider using a **function** instead of a procedure as you can use it in SQL statements, while procedure requires PL/SQL so you can't e.g.

```
select net_salary(10, 0.1, ???what to put here???) from dual;
```

If it were a function, you'd

```
select net_salary(10, 0.1) from dual;
```